# How to add constraint resolver in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following on an ASP.NET MVC 5 project:

```
DefaultInlineConstraintResolver resolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
resolver.ConstraintMap.Add("notetype", typeof(EnumConstraint<NoteType>));
RouteTable.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(resolver);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(resolver);
```

On the last line the resolver is not accepted on MapHttpAttributeRoutes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DefaultInlineConstraintResolver resolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
resolver.ConstraintMap.Add("notetype", typeof(EnumConstraint<NoteType>));
RouteTable.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(resolver);
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new HttpRouteBuilder(resolver));
```

Comment: Yes, I did try that ... Where is HttpRouteBuilder? I can't find it anywhere ... I tried System.Web.Http; and it is not there.

Comment: HttpRouteBuilder is the class that takes a tokenized route template and creates an IHttpRoute for it. I am searching for a good example for this,where you cas see and get it.

Comment: check this link [link](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Attribute%20routing%20in%20Web%20API) and see the Extensibility section. This will give you an idea.

Comment: Yes, I did read that ... But it seems HttpRouteBuilder was removed on RC. How can I solve this?